# How do I display images in my JSP (Annotation based Spring Web MVC Project)?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, annotations, javabeans

I need to display an image in my project. I'm using NetBeans IDE. I can't use XML in this project since everything is annotation based, hence this is how I call* my dispatcher servlet in my `AppInit.java` class:
*(if "call" is the apt term)

```
public class AppInit implements WebApplicationInitializer{

    @Override
    public void onStartup(javax.servlet.ServletContext container) throws javax.servlet.ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(MVCConfigurer.class);
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }

}
```

I've checked some other answers in this website but all of them are XML based and advise to include something like the following strip of code in the `dispatcher-servlet.xml` file:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/**"> </mvc:resources>
```

I cannot afford to reconfigure my whole project using XML.

My beans are defined in the `MVCConfigurer.java` file like so:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.lfa.emsys")
@PropertySource(value="classpath:db.properties")
class MVCConfigurer extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
    @Value("${jdbc.driverClassName}")
    private String jdbcDriver;

    @Value("${jdbc.url}")
    private String jdbcUrl;

    @Value("${jdbc.username}")
    private String jdbcUsername;

    @Value("${jdbc.password}")
    private String jdbcPassword;

    @Value("${view.prefix}")
    private String viewPrefix;

    @Value("${view.suffix}")
    private String viewSuffix;

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver vr = new InternalResourceViewResolver(viewPrefix, viewSuffix);
        return vr;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource(){
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(jdbcDriver);
        dataSource.setUrl(jdbcUrl);
        dataSource.setUsername(jdbcUsername);
        dataSource.setPassword(jdbcPassword);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate(){
        JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(getDataSource());
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory(){
        LocalSessionFactoryBean bean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        bean.setDataSource(getDataSource());
        bean.setPackagesToScan("com.lfa.emsys.entity");
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        bean.setHibernateProperties(properties);
        return bean;
    }

}
```

How can I display the `stack.jpg` image in my `index.jsp` webpage?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! I put my `stack.jpg` file in the `src/main/resources/assets` folder like so:

[image]

**NOTE**: I created the `resources` and `assets` folders manually.

The I added this strip of code in my `MVCConfigurer.java` class:

```
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:assets/");
    }
```

I inserted the image in my `index.jsp` file like so:

```
<img src = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/stack.jpg"/>
```

It worked. I was looking for a translation of the following line of XML code to an Annotation based form:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/resources/assets/" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't just use an image tag on the JSP, like this:

`<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/stack.JPG"/>`

Comment: That gives me a default crashed image logo. I think that's because while dealing with static content in servlets we need to serve it in a different way (?), which is what I was looking for by posting this question here. I'm fairly new to this stuff.

Comment: What does the folder structure of your built war file look like? You should be able to open it up with your favorite zip utility (7-zip or whatever).

Comment: The resources config examples you're finding that use xml are for configuring your spring app so that static resources don't have to go through the Spring request dispatcher servlet.  This is just a performance optimization because there's no need to hit that servlet if you're just serving static content. To just show an image on a page, an image tag will work just fine as long as it's in the built war file. The image is either not getting included in the war file or the pathing may be wrong.